# Get metadata of file in objective-c / cocoa

Tags: objective-c, file, metadata

I would like to get the metadata (if this is an image, the size for instance) using objective-c.

Do you knwo how I can achieve this?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 1):

Methods depend on what you need exactly.

File properties can be retrieved from the file itself (e.g. file size etc) - use `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` method in `NSFileManager` for that.

If you want to get image properties you can use `CGImageSource...` set of functions. You can find thorough tutorial on how it can be done [here](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/09/accessing-image-properties-without-loading-the-image-into-memory/)